# Re-Write T-SQL query in Linq-to-Entities - C#

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities, common-table-expression

Any one who knows this please help,

How can I re-write the following SQL Stored procedure in Linq to Entities?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleSP]
AS BEGIN
        ;with CTE_MyData(Col1, Col2,Col3 ) AS
        (
            SELECT DC.Name, DT.Name, RD.Col3 FROM MyData RD
            INNER JOIN FoodType DT ON RD.FoodId = DT.FoodId
            INNER JOIN FoodCategory DC ON DT.FoodCategoryId = DC.FoodCategoryId
        )
        SELECT Col1,
                CASE
                    WHEN GROUPING(Col2) = '' THEN Col2
                    ELSE Col1
                END [Food Column],
            SUM(Col3) AS Col3
        FROM CTE_MyData
        GROUP BY Col1, Col2 WITH ROLLUP
        HAVING GROUPING(Col1) = 0

END
```

Comment: A workaround will be to create an anonymous type and query your result from it . or if it helps you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264573/writing-case-statements-using-linq-with-group-by

Comment: Common Table Expression in LINQ? Don't think so. Stick with SP, unless you can get rid of CTE at the first place.